# service worker image cache

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, service-worker

My service worker perform a cache on my offline.html and resources ( jpg, js, css files) for this html page. That works so good for a few hours but after that, only remains cached the offline.html but not the jpg, js, css files.

I wonder if the browser has a limit (time, weigth, etc). the service worker fails?  Do I should use cache.put instead cache.addAll?, why is failing?.

```
//This is the "Offline page" service worker

//Install stage sets up the offline page in the cahche and opens a new cache
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) { 
  var offlinePage = new Request('offline.html');
  event.waitUntil(
  fetch(offlinePage).then(function(response) {
    return caches.open('offline1').then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[off] Cached offline page during Install'+ response.url);
      return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
    }); 
  }));
});

//If any fetch fails, it will show the offline page.    
//Maybe this should be limited to HTML documents?
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function(error) {
        console.error( '[off] Network request Failed. Serving offline page ' + error );
        return caches.open('offline1').then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match('offline.html');
      });
    }));
});


//cache of files that are part of offline.html cache.put
var ASSETS = [

          '/pwa/offline/js/main.js',          
          '/upload/off-1about.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1best-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1gallery-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1intro-bg.jpg',        
          '/upload/off-1logo.png',
          '/upload/off-1menu-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-best-01.jpg',
          '/upload/off-best-02.jpg',              
          '/upload/off-best-03.jpg',
          '/upload/off-call-me-32.png'            
          ];
self.oninstall = function (evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(caches.open('offline1').then(function (cache) {
    return Promise.all(ASSETS.map(function (url) {
      return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        return cache.put(url, response);
      });
    }));
  }))
};

// or

//cache of files that are part of offline.html cache.addAll
/*
var ASSETS = [

          '/pwa/offline/js/main.js',          
          '/upload/off-1about.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1best-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1gallery-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-1intro-bg.jpg',        
          '/upload/off-1logo.png',
          '/upload/off-1menu-bg.jpg',
          '/upload/off-best-01.jpg',
          '/upload/off-best-02.jpg',              
          '/upload/off-best-03.jpg',
          '/upload/off-call-me-32.png'            
          ];
self.oninstall = function (evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(caches.open('offline-cache-name').then(function (cache) {
    return cache.addAll(ASSETS);
  }))
};
*/

//This is a event that can be fired from your page to tell the SW to update the offline page
self.addEventListener('refreshOffline', function(response) {
  return caches.open('offline1').then(function(cache) {
    console.log('[off] Offline page updated from refreshOffline event: '+ response.url);
    return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Ok solved… if images are not caching, use the uncommon jpeg for your offline page images, and use htaccess to cache them. That makes the trick. Also cache there the js and css necessary.

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.(jpeg)$">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

Comment: <FilesMatch "^(off-1logo\.png|off-call-me-32\.png|sw-register\.js)$">    
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>